# Change how autocomplete columnizes large text arrays

Tags: python, autocomplete, readline

I'm writing a CLI in python for work purposes and i'd like to improve how tab to autocomplete columnizes large text arrays.

Here's an example:

```
import cmd, os
class test(cmd.Cmd):
    # Fetch a large array of text entries by linting a directory
    files = os.listdir('C:/WINDOWS')

    # This returns what i'd expect from a columnized large list
    def do_list(self, text):
        print cmd.Cmd().columnize(self.files)

    # Same large list via autocomplete, result is columnized, but not in same way
    def complete_list(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        if text:
            return [x for x in self.files if x.lower().startswith(text.lower())]
        return self.files

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().cmdloop()
```

do_list will produce nice long columns of files. complete_list will produce a not-so-nice columnized list of files with many columns of 4 elements each + wide gaps between them. Which forces me to scroll right to see all results.

Is there a way to change autocomplete's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a compromise than an aswer, but at least it gives me the result i want. In short: i used os.path.commonprefix to do autocomplete's job and return the common prefix when hitting tab, and before i return the results i print a properly columnized list of matches.

```
import cmd, os

class test(cmd.Cmd):
    # Fetch a large array of text entries by linting a directory
    files = sorted(os.listdir('C:/WINDOWS'))

    def do_list(self, text):
        cmd.Cmd().columnize(self.files)

    def complete_list(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        if text:
            matches = [x for x in self.files if x.lower().startswith(text.lower())]

            print
            cmd.Cmd().columnize(matches)
            print
            return [os.path.commonprefix([x.lower() for x in matches])]

        print
        cmd.Cmd().columnize(self.files)
        print
        return []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().cmdloop()
```

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but it did the trick.